# RPM Build Spec file i want to check rpm is being install or update

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

i want to check the rpm i have created is install or update by user(client)
like

```
rpm -ivh abc.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -Uvh abc.rpm
```

is their any %command in spec file to get info regarding this command.

my requirement is if i have a rpm named abc-0.1-2.rpm and now user want to install it prior installing abc.0.1-1.rpm with command
`rpm -ivh abc.0.1-2.rpm` then it allow to install 
or user directly update rpm with command `rpm -Uvh abc.0.1-2` before installing the older version then stop to doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%pre[un]` and `%post[un]` scripts are given "a number representing the number of instances of the package currently installed on the system, after the current package has been installed or erased," so that tells you if the RPM is currently installed or not. See [this section of Maximum RPM](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html).

Comment: what about %postun? how to detect if the package is being removed by user as apposed to being removed by rpm to be upgraded to another version? what would $1 variable have in that case?

Comment: Then you would get `0`, as explained in the reference.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on the above:

In your `%post[un]` or `%pre[un]` sections there's a variable you can check to see if this package already exists on the system (is being updated/cleanup from upgrade) or not (first time install/final uninstall).

It looks like this:

```
%post
if [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "First install complete"
else
    echo "Upgrade complete"
fi
```